# execute shell command with variable

Tags: shell, echo

To execute 'find' with some variables from txt file i made this
but it doesn't work.
is that wrong with execute statement?

```
#/bin/bash 
while read line; 
do 
   echo tmp_name: $line
   for ST in 'service.getFile("'$line;
           do
                   find ./compact/ -type f -exec grep -l $ST {} \;
           done
done < tmpNameList.txt
```

Comment: What is `service.getFile(` supposed to be? It's not a syntax recognized by bash.

Comment: no problem with $ST$line. echo $ST is just string. ST="service.getFile(\"$line "

Answer (score 1):

Try and quote `$ST` in your `find` command.

What's more:

- since you operate from the current directory, `./` is not necessary;
- you don't seem to have any special regex character (the `(` needs to be quoted in `grep`'s classical regex mode, and I assume you *did* mean a literal dot), so use `fgrep` instead (or `grep -F`). Ie:

  ```
             find compact/ -type f -exec fgrep -l "$ST" {} \;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` can read multiple patterns from a file (`-f` option):

```
find ./compact/ -type f -exec grep -f patterns.txt {} +
```

where `patterns.txt` (prepend `'service.getFile('` to each line) is:

```
sed 's/^/service.getFile(/' tmpNameList.txt >patterns.txt
```